# A div is not showing up in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I've built a webpage, everything looks great in IE7 and upwards but in IE6 it's looks bad.

I have a whole div which has a background image that's not even showing up.

Why could this be? Are there common things that tend to not work that could be in my CSS? I don't normally support IE6 so don't usually have to figure these things out, but my client has specified that they want to work in IE6.

Here's the site, yep - quite a nice site in modern browsers! http://www.replyonline.co.uk/ie6sucks/index.html - feel free to look through the code (there's a IE6 specific stylesheet at view-source:http://www.replyonline.co.uk/ie6sucks/css/anythingslider-ie.css where I've solved some of the existing issues.

Thanks

Comment: One of the things bugging me is there appears to be a big margin on the right of the wrapper although there appears to be nothing causing this?

Comment: Have you thought perhaps it may be because IE6 is a heap of steaming excrement? :-)

Comment: There is the option not to support IE6, Google have dropped support for it, other people have, I'm going to too.

Comment: Yep IE6 is a bitch. But in this case, I really need to support it on this site for the client.

Comment: I don't have IE6 here. Which element gets hidden?

Comment: @Tim - any time a client asks for IE6, I tell them it will double the cost of development, and result in reduced functionality. They usually get the message. Also, remember there's a difference between "supporting" IE6 so that the site's basic functionality works, and making it look perfect in IE6. It's quite common to allow a site to not look so good in IE6 as it does in other sites, and as long as things still actually work, they can still claim to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an IE6 install with me here, but here are a few hints:

It's most likely a positioning ('hasLayout') issue. Try setting `zoom: 1` on the missing DIV or its parent(s). The same goes for `position: relative` or a combination of both.

Also, check some of the content-hiding bugs on PIE: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

You can use the Internet Explorer developer toolbar to try some of this out: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535. Keep in mind though that some bugs will only appear or get fixed on a full page reload, and not while fiddling with the CSS in the developer toolbar.

I also use XRAY ( http://www.westciv.com/xray ) a lot to see how my elements behave.

For more info on 'having layout', see http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html.

Comment: Good answer.. Plenty of info there.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure your site validates: [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.replyonline.co.uk%2Fie6sucks%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) Currently yours doesn't ( 146 Errors, 16 warning ).

2 - There's an annoying bug in IE to do with `margin/padding`, if you have any to the left or right of an element, you may need to do `display: inline` or `inline-block`;

I've found little things like this can help.

Looking at the W3C results, it looks like you may have too many closing `div` tags

Comment: Thanks, just managed to reduce the sites validation to 24 errors, those mainly beyond my control. I'll have a look at the other thing.

Comment: Yeah, you can ignore the `alt` bit as there not major.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to debug since I don't have a working copy of ie6 on my machine, only ietester but there are known issues with ie6 where it doesn't calculate sizes properly in order to display background images properly.

The answer generally is to trigger hasLayout on the element and the easiest way to do this is using `position:relative`. I'd give that a go before anything else.

I would also recommend having a look at the [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) stylesheet to see if there is anything there that you can make use of. The reset/reassign css in there is simply brilliant and irons out a lot of css issues.

Best of luck!